# Multiple if-or statement for a getelementbyid in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to ensure that the information put into a field is not null, of a certain length and does not contain letters.

```
var Xlength = document.getElementById('X')
if( document.getElementById('X').value === '' || Xlength.innerHTML.length != 16 || isNaN(Xlength) )
```

When I test the code however, it always comes up as false. Is there a simple syntax issue in this question, or am I misunderstanding something more crucial?

Comment: try `isNaN(Xlength.value)`

Comment: please edit your question by wrapping your code in the code formatter

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `X` is an input field, then `var Xlength = document.getElementById('X')` will select this input field. This variable isn't named well in that case, since it's the field itself, and not the length of whatever input it contains.

`document.getElementById('X').value === ''` will be false if there is something entered in the field, because it will not be empty.

`Xlength.innerHTML.length != 16` isn't meaningful, because there is no innerHTML; what you really want is `Xlength.value.length`. Furthermore, `Xlength.value.length != 16` evaluates to `true` if `length <= 15` or `length >= 17`, which is also probably not what you really want, so I would adjust this equality check to something like `Xlength.value.length < 16`

`isNaN(Xlength)` is not meaningful to include.

I would rewrite this as:

```
var Xval = document.getElementById('X').value;
    // or, optionally
var Xval = document.getElementById('X').value.trim();
    // removes extra white space
if(Xval.length > 0 && Xval.length < 16){
    // is not empty and less than 16 characters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write like this:

document.getElementById('X'), it doesn't mean any length it means a DOM element.

so **isNaN(Xlength) will always be true**

Also, **document.getElementById('X').value this will be undefined** always because there is no 'value' on DOM element.

Here, Xlength.innerHTML.length != 16 may be false because the content may not be 16 for this element

Comment: If you bold 90% of the text, the boldness loses its effect.